# How do I configure Apache to serve https?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, https, apache-virtualhost

After many hours I finally managed to configure Apache to use my SSL certificate but i just found out that there is something wrong in my configuration. If I try to reach my domain from Google Chrome by just entering the following address I get the following warning:

```
 erichermansson.com

 Forbidden
 You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

But if I enter the following address in Google Chrome I can access the server and its working with my certificate:

```
 https://erichermansson.com
```

What do I do wrong?

Here is my VirtualHost:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin admin@erichermansson.com
ServerName erichermansson.com
ServerAlias www.erichermansson.com
SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile /www/erichermansson.com/ssl/erichermansson.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /www/erichermansson.com/ssl/erichermansson.com.key
DocumentRoot /www/erichermansson.com/html/
ErrorLog /www/erichermansson.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /www/erichermansson.com/logs/access.log combined
<Directory /www/erichermansson.com/html/ >
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you defined a `VirtualHost:` entry for port `80` somewhere ?

Comment: And does Apache have read permission on `/var/erichermansson.com/html`?

Comment: @Sreeraj No I have not done that, where do I do that?

Comment: @garethTheRed Yes, Apache have read permission on the HTML folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTP to redirect to HTTPS you need to (the first 3 steps you probably already did):

1. Allow port 80 in your router.
2. Forward port 80 to your server.
3. Punch hole in your firewall:

   ```
   sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
   ```
4. **Define VirtualHost for port 80** (as well as for 443):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName             erichermansson.com
     ServerAlias            www.erichermansson.com
     RewriteEngine          on
     RewriteCond            %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
     RewriteRule            ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R]
     RewriteCond            %{HTTPS} !on
     RewriteRule            ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301]
   </VirtualHost>

   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

     <VirtualHost *:443>

     ... your code here ...

     </VirtualHost>

   </IfModule>
   ```
5. Activate `mod_rewrite`:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   ```
6. Define a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, something like:

   ```
   RewriteCond            %{HTTPS} !on
   RewriteRule            ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301]
   ```

   **which we have already done step 4.**
7. And finally restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you be more specific how I define a VirtualHost for port 80 and how I use mod_rewrite? Thanks!

Comment: Take your time! :)

Comment: if he is getting that error, port 80 is not firewalled, as Apache is answering. The problem at the moment is that the vhost is not listening to port 80.

Comment: Would not one RewriteCond rule be enough? It if is a new site, a RedirectPermanent is simpler and does the job.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro This code I use on my server. I am no expert on rewrites, always been busy not to learn it properly. If you are able to improve it, I would appretiate it.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Should I change the https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 to something specific or just leave it like that?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil So I tried what u said and it worked, many thanks! If I would like to do this on my subdomains, can I use the same VirtualHost but just change ServerName etc.?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil I'll check it out, thanks for your answer :)